# How can I select a specific marker from my array?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I found something that is close to my problem here: [Storing Google Map Markers and Selecting a specific marker from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059940/storing-google-map-markers-and-selecting-a-specific-marker-from-it)

However, I've studied the code there hard and I just can't quite figure out how to implement it into mine. Here is what I have:

```
var t = {
    name:"sdf",
    lat:123,
    lng:-123,
    address:"asd",
  link:"http://www.google.com"
  };

  a[0] = t;

  var t = {
    name:"sdf",
    lat:123,
    lng:-123,
    address:"asd",
    link:"http://www.google.com"
  };

  a[1] = t;

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(a[i].lat,a[i].lng);
        map.addMarker(createMarker(a[i].name,latlng,a[i].address,a[i].link));
     };
```

This code is within the initialize function.

I placed this code outside the function after the dom listener for initialize:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker[[a[0]], "click",function(){
      alert("worked!")
    });
```

Thing is, I need to be able to select a specific marker to do something different than the rest.

I even tried giving an additional variable the same value as a[0] sort of like what they did in the link. But putting that variable in the marker brackets didn't work either.

Here is the code that creates the markers:

```
function createMarker(name,latlng,address,link) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latlng, map: map});
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
      if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:"<div class='buildingInfo'>" + name + "<br>" + "<a href='" + link + "'>" + address +"</a>" + "</div>"});
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    return marker;

  };
```

Comment: @geocodezip omg seriously? Will you stop getting so technical and downvoting my posts? I don't care what they contain! I am trying to select a specific one. They are placed in an array using a[0] = t. Please stop focusing on the content within my code and instead please focus on my code.

Comment: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697284/google-api-multiple-markers-with-different-colours-depending-on-a-class/24697331#24697331** I think it help

Answer (score 0):

As much as I would have preferred to directly select the marker, I settled for the following code:

```
function createMarker(name,latlng,address,link) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latlng, map: map});
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
      if(name == "name"){
        alert("worked!");
      }
      if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:"<div class='buildingInfo'>" + name + "<br>" + "<a href='" + link + "'>" + address +"</a>" + "</div>"});
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    return marker;

  };
```

I think since the marker already had a listener, it probably would not have worked anyway to add another listener to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do something when you click a marker, you don't need to attribute an ID. You just need to link a listener to markers when you create them.

You store markers data in an array of objects...

```
var markersData = [
  {
      lat: 40.6386333,
      lng: -8.745,
      name: "Marker 1"
   },
   {
      lat: 40.59955,
      lng: -8.7498167,
      name: "Marker 2"
   }
];
```

Now you have Marker 1 in markersData[0] and Marker 2 in markersData[1].

A trivial initialize function. Note that you start markers creation with a call to displayMarkers().

```
function initialize() {
   var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.601203,-8.668173),
      zoom: 9,
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
   };

   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

   // displayMarkers() function is called to begin the markers creation
   displayMarkers();
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Now the displayMarkers function:

```
// This function will iterate over markersData array
// creating markers with createMarker function
function displayMarkers(){

   // this variable sets the map bounds and zoom level according to markers position
   var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

   // For loop that runs through the info on markersData making
   // it possible to createMarker function to create the markers
   for (var i = 0; i < markersData.length; i++){

      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(markersData[i].lat, markersData[i].lng);
      var name = markersData[i].name;

      createMarker(latlng, name);

      // Marker’s Lat. and Lng. values are added to bounds variable
      bounds.extend(latlng); 
   }

   // Finally the bounds variable is used to set the map bounds
   // with API’s fitBounds() function
   map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

Finally the createMarkers function, where you set the listener to do what ever you want it to do

```
// This function creates markers (one at a time) and sets a listener to each marker
function createMarker(latlng, name){
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: latlng
   });

   // THIS IS WHAT YOU WANT...
   // This event expects a click on a marker
   // When this event is fired it opens the alert message
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

      alert("worked! This is marker: " + name);

   });
}
```

Comment: This is essentially what I explained I had to do in the answer I put. In your createMarker(latlng, name) function, your alert can then specify which marker is being clicked. However, and I probably didn't explain this part well enough, I needed to add a listener to only a specific marker, not all. Which is how I came to my conclusion below. I just forgot to show I added the name: attribute to my array of markers.